# Jquery - Unable to submit form if a change is made to a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if someone could help me out.

I need to work something out.

I have a form with a textarea, if a user hits the submit button, i need to check if the values in the textarea has changed, if it has, return an alert, if they havent changed, then submit the form.

I can disable the submit button if the values have changed by

```
$('#textarea').on('input', function() {
    $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
});
```

But this isnt really what i need to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, im a bit of a newb at jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: One way will be to use Knockout.js (or similar), so when user changes text for the first time, you’ll have a flag raised in javascript (like isChanged = true). I’m not sure it’s the most efficient way, but it works 

Comment: Not sure how that could be working since `input` is not a jQuery _event_.  Please refer to the documentation:  http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. Hope it will work for you.

```
//tracking changes
var isChanged = false;

$('#textarea').on('change', function() {
    isChanged = true;
});

// bind submit event handler
$('#form').submit(function(){
    if(isChanged){
        //alert
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i have at the moment